# how to use require to include a gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm new to Ruby coding. I'm just learning gem/bundle and require. At first, I think the gem should be like jar in Java and pip in Python. So I searched a very simple package named "haha" on rubygems.org -- https://rubygems.org/search?query=haha -- to have a test. But soon I found there always be error and I don't know why. Here's the details --

1. `gem install "haha"` -- it runs fine and I found it in the lib folder --

   ```
   C:\Ruby31-x64\lib\ruby\gems\3.1.0\gems>dir |findstr haha
   2022-04-25  17:34    <DIR>          haha-1.1.0
   2022-04-25  17:34    <DIR>          haha-1.2.0
   ```

   So I think this gem "haha" has been installed successfully.
2. Then in irb, I tried "require" to include it, then it failes --

   ```
   irb(main):002:0> require "haha"
   C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/haha-1.2.0/lib/haha/translator.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Haha (NameError)

   class Haha::Translator
         ^^^^
   Did you mean?  Hash
           from <internal:C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
           from <internal:C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
           from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/haha-1.2.0/lib/haha.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
           from <internal:C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:160:in `require'
           from <internal:C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:160:in `rescue in require'
           from <internal:C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:149:in `require'
           from (irb):2:in `<main>'
           from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/irb-1.4.1/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
           from C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/irb:33:in `load'
           from C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/irb:33:in `<main>'
   <internal:C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require': cannot load such file -- haha (LoadError)
           from <internal:C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
           from (irb):2:in `<main>'
           from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/irb-1.4.1/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
           from C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/irb:33:in `load'
           from C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/irb:33:in `<main>'
   ```
3. I checked the $LOAD_PATH and it looks correct --

   ```
   irb(main):003:0> pp $LOAD_PATH
   ["C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/haha-1.2.0/lib",
    "C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0",
    "C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/x64-ucrt",
    "C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby",
    "C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/3.1.0",
    "C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/3.1.0/x64-ucrt",
    "C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby",
    "C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0",
    "C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/x64-mingw-ucrt"]
   ```

   I think being a package on rubygems this "haha" should be a correct one and it must be my fault somewhere so that I can't "require" it in irb. But I really don't know what's my mistake.

Please kind help.

Comment: It is not you. It is the gem being broken because it defines `class Haha::Translator` but `Haha` isn't defined at that point in time. That gem is extremely simple, it basically has only one method that can only produce two different possible return values. Feels like it was just a test project (and should probably be deleted). Why don't you just reimplement the behavior in a simple method?

Comment: @spickermann Thanks for your reply. It makes me feel better. As I just said-- I'm just new to Ruby so that I'm looking for some very simple sample to show me how to use "gem", "bundle" and "require" ... :)

Comment: This is a pretty good into the how and why with gems and Bundler. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4DqzaqeeMgY